# Restrict inputtext to Y or N in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I would like to restrict the input in a inputText to Y or N. Following is what I thought of. Is this correct way or any better way is possible ?

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.field}" id="myID" title="Enter Y or N"
  onkeypress ="if(!(event.keyCode == 89 || event.keyCode == 78)) event.keyCode=null;" />  

<p:tooltip for="myID" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
```

validateRegex can be used but I want to restrict the input as the user input the value and not on submit.

Comment: Is it reasonable for you to switch to a SelectOneMenu? You could then just present them with Y or N and they can't chose anything else.

Comment: or selectOneRadio, selectOneButton, selectBooleanCheckbox, selectOneListbox.

Comment: @Cagatay Civici, selectBooleanCheckbox requires true or false as values and I want Y or N as values. My database column is char(1) holding Y or N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validator as the user input too, this way:

```
<p:inputText id="idfield" value="#{myBean.field}"
                validatorMessage="Only Y or N">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[Y N]*" />
                <p:ajax update="msg" event="keyup" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="idfield" id="msg" display="icon" />
```

I think you'll solve your problem that way.
(You may have to change [Y N]* for [Y N] as i'm not sure about that *)

Nevertheless, in my apps I use, for Y or N, this:

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="sor"
 value="#{myBean.value}">
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="Y" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="N" itemValue="N" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

With char(1) on database too. Works great.

Comment: I will go with selectOneRadio. Thanks @Maco